# Is this edge-partitioning NP-Hard?

Tags: graph-algorithms, np-hardness, partition-problem

Let $G = (V,E)$ be an undirected graph with $m = |E|$ edges (assume that $m = 3t$ for some $t \in \mathbb{N}$).

**Problem:** Partition $E$ to $q = \frac{m}{3}$ sets $S_1,S_2,\ldots, S_q \subseteq E$ sets such that for each $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,q\}$  it holds that (1) $|S_i| = 3$ and (2) $S_i$ induces a forest (graph with no cycles) in $G$.

**Question:** Is the above problem NP-Hard for a general graph $G$?

Comment: Is your graph simple, or do you allow multiple edges? For simple graphs, you always have such a partition for $m\ge 6$.

Comment: Even if there exists such a partition, can you find it in polynomial time? additionally, for non-simple graphs, does it become NP-Hard?

Comment: Please reedit the question to make it more precise.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. When you say a set $S_i$ "induces a forest", knowing that $|S_i| = 3$, do you just mean that the three edges of $S_i$ should not form a triangle?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. Assume that there can be repetitions of the edges.

Answer (score 1):

This question boils down to answering to simpler questions.

Can you find a graph with 6 edges where it is impossible to partition the edges?

In a graph of more than 6 edges can you always find a triple of edges that is not a forest?

Comment: Is there a known answer to the question you mentioned? does it imply NP-hardness/polynomial time algorithm for my problem?